# Generating data with SQL

Tags: php, xml

I have an SQL statement that fetches information and puts it into XML nodes. One of these nodes is imageurl. In this node there needs to be a list of URLs that I'm getting from the database.

What I'm trying at the moment is my original query which is:

```
SELECT ultrait_wpl_properties.id, location1_name, location3_name, location4_name, field_312, field_42, post_code, lot_area, living_area, price, bedrooms, bathrooms, field_308, googlemap_lt, googlemap_ln, street, street_no, ultrait_wpl_property_types.name, property_title, build_year, add_date, ultrait_wpl_items.item_name 
    FROM ultrait_wpl_properties 
    JOIN ultrait_wpl_property_types ON ultrait_wpl_properties.property_type = ultrait_wpl_property_types.id 
    JOIN ultrait_wpl_items ON ultrait_wpl_properties.id = ultrait_wpl_items.parent_id 
    ORDER BY ultrait_wpl_properties.id
```

Then when i get to the node I want I have this query

```
    $sqli = "SELECT item_name
    FROM ultrait_wpl_items, ultrait_wpl_properties
    WHERE ultrait_wpl_items.parent_id = ultrait_wpl_properties.id
    AND ultrait_wpl_properties.id = $propertyid";

    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sqli);

    foreach($results as $row){ // foreach loop to iterate over the data in the $result array
        $images = $row->item_name;
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is generate the data I need for the rest of the nodes like so...

```
<root>
<property>
<id>5</id>
<area>United States</area>
<country/>
<city/>
<town>Property in Spain</town>       
<towninner/>
<postcode/>
<lot_area>10000</lot_area>
<living_area>4000</living_area>
<price>100000</price>
<bedrooms>0</bedrooms>
<bathrooms>2</bathrooms>
<summary><p>Description</p></summary>
<latitude>21.3239718</latitude>
<longlitude>-157.87649799999997</longlitude>
<street/>
<streetno/>
<type>Office</type>
<property_title/>
<build_year>1978</build_year>
<add_date>2015-01-13 16:48:08</add_date>
<imageurl></imageurl>
</property>
```

But where it says imageurl you can see one item. Each property may have multiple pictures attached.

When I get to imageurl I tried the second code block you can see, what I'm aiming for is something like this:

```
<imageurl>link 1</imageurl>
<imageurl>link 2</imageurl>
<imageurl>link 3</imageurl>
<imageurl>link 4</imageurl>
```

But the reason this has been difficult because my original query returned a duplicate property node, just with the next URL in. I need one property node per ID but multiple pictures in the imageurl node.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to split the query. Do the imageurl part separately, especially if you have stored those imageurls each in its own row.